# Pass Python function from outside to another function

Tags: python

I have a function, which calculate features from my data.
Here is a dummy sample of it

```
import numpy as np
val1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
val2=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]
data=[]
def feature_cal(val):
    val=np.array(val)
    value=val*2
    data.append(np.mean(value))
feature_cal(val1)
feature_cal(val2)
```

What i want is to define the function np.mean() out of my function feature_cal.
**Pseudo code**

```
def feature_cal(val,method):
    val=np.array(val)
    value=val*2
    data.append(method(value))
feature_cal(val1,method=np.mean())
feature_cal(val2,method=np.mean())
```

This will help me to calculate other features such as np.std(), np.var() without changing the original function

Comment: Remove paranthesis: `feature_cal(val1,method=np.mean)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass the function you need to remove the parentheses after `np.mean`:

```
import numpy as np

def feature_cal(val, method):
    val = np.array(val)
    value = val*2
    data.append(method(value))

feature_cal(val1, method=np.mean)
feature_cal(val2, method=np.mean)
```

---

## EDIT

If you need to pass arguments to `np.mean` you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import numpy as np
import functools

def feature_cal(val, method):
    val = np.array(val)
    value = val*2
    data.append(method(value))

bound_function = functools.partial(np.mean, axis=1)
feature_cal(val1, method=bound_function)
feature_cal(val2, method=bound_function)
```

Comment: if i have to pass some parameters  to np.mean() such as axis=0 or axis=1. How can i pass it this way when i am not using parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly you need to pass callable and not result of function invocation as you do now. So this line

```
feature_cal(val1,method=np.mean())
```

Shouls read

```
feature_cal(val1,method=np.mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply insert a method as a parameter into a function by entering the name of the method (without parentheses) and by reading the function you will call(with parentheses) the inserted parameter

```
    def feature_cal(val,method):
        val=np.array(val)
        value=val*2
        data.append(method(value))



   feature_cal(val1,method=np.mean)
```